# Does the expect's 'spawn' command passes the parameters securely?

Tags: linux, bash, passwords, expect, spawn

I have the following expect script which executes 'myexe' and passes some password as argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
gets stdin pwd

log_user 0

eval spawn "/myexe ${pwd}"

log_user 1
expect eof
catch wait result
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

My executable 'myexe' is compiled Linux executable (not shell script) and the goal is to pass a password securely to it. Unfortunately the executable doesn't read the stdin for the password, but instead expects it as a start parameter.

When I execute the following expect script I cannot see my 'myexe' executable with 'ps'. Does somebody know if the 'spawn' performed by the expect is secure enough? Would the password be visible somewhere else (/proc for instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `eval` here. It could be disastrous, depending on the contents of the password. This should suffice:

```
spawn /myexe $pwd
```

Anyone doing a `ps -ef` while myexe is running will be able to see the password.